# Why is the compiler choosing this template function over an overloaded non-template function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, implicit-conversion, type-constraints

Using VC++ 2010, given the following:

```
class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

template<class T> void foo(T& t);  // A
void foo(Base& base);              // B

Derived d;
foo(d);                            // calls A
foo(static_cast<Base&>(d));        // calls B
```

I would like "B" to be called above. I can achieve this with a cast to `Base`, but why is this necessary?

I want the template function to be called for all types not derived from `Base` (built-in types, etc.), but I want the non-template overload to be called for types derived from `Base`, without requiring the client to explicitly cast. I also tried making the overload a specialization of the template, but the same behavior occurs in that case. What is the idiomatic way to get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All things being equal, nontemplate functions are preferred over function templates.  However, in your scenario, all things are not equal:  (A) is an exact match with `T = Derived`, but (B) requires a derived-to-base conversion of the argument.

You can work around this for specific cases (like this one) by using SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error) to prevent (A) from being instantiated with a type that is derived from `Base`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value
>::type foo(T& x)
{
}

void foo(Base& x)
{
}
```

Comment: Is this a c++11 thing or does it work in older code as well - just asking because it's cool :)?

Comment: @w00te:  `is_base_of` and `enable_if` are included in Boost, C++ TR1, and C++11.  No C++11 functionality is required for them; you can define these using only C++03 language features.

Comment: @w00te: you can do it in C++03, but you have to grab `enable_if` and `is_base_of` from boost (or roll your own, this will teach you a few things about C++).

Comment: I was hoping for something a little less C++11-ish.  My code is multi-platform and I'm not sure I can rely on anything post C++03.  How would this have been solved in, say, 2001?

Comment: @Tabber33:  This is how this problem would have been solved in 2001.  There is nothing exciting and new here.  Take a look at the Boost implementations of `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_base_of` if you'd like to implement them yourself; it's not more than 50 lines of code.

Comment: How do you feel about that solution vs. just changing the name of the non-template foo to, say, fooBase?  I guess the client must know when he's calling the version for a Base object -- pros/cons?

Comment: @Tabber33 : With an example as arbitrary as `foo` I don't think you can get a meaningful opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The template version is being selected because it is a better match when called with an argument of type `Derived` than the overloaded version. You can use SFINAE to drop the template version from overload resolution so that the other version is selected when calling with arguments of type `Base` or `Derived`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

template<class T> 
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value == false
>::type
foo(T&)  
{ 
  std::cout << "template foo" << std::endl; 
}


void foo(Base&)
{ 
  std::cout << "non-template foo" << std::endl; 
}


int main()
{
  Derived d;
  Base b;

  foo( d );
  foo( b );
}
```

Comment: `is_same` it unnecessary here.