# How can I use SFINAE to prioritise a non-templated function while also providing a return type?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

*EDIT*: With apologies for the bad code before. Here is a compilable example that demonstrates the problem

I'm trying to implement a visitor that simplifies to this basic pattern:

```
class Base {};

class BaseA : public Base {};
class BaseB : public Base {};

class DerivedA : public BaseA {
public:
    int operator+(DerivedA const& a) const
    {
        return 10;
    }
};

class DerivedB : public BaseB {
public:
    int operator+(DerivedB const& b) const
    {
        return 10;
    }
};

struct Adder
{
    int operator()(BaseA const& a, BaseB const& b)
    {
        std::cout << "Addition is not supported for these types.";
        return -1;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    int operator()(T const& a, U const& b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedA a;
    DerivedB b;
    Adder adder;
    adder(a, a);
    adder(b, b);
    adder(a, b); // Compiler chooses templated function and fails if 
                 // operator+ is not supported.
}
```

Where the base types match (which I have set up to be cases where `operator+` is not supported), I would like the compiler to choose the non-templated function. However, it is not.

I believe I know why (direct template match is better than base class match), and the solution to [Why is the compiler choosing this template function over an overloaded non-template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8594326/794283) involving Substition Failure Is Not An Error (SFINAE) and `std::enable_if` seems very close.

However, that solution only seems to be applicable to functions that return `void`. How can I adapt that SFINAE approach to allow me to provide a return type?

See http://ideone.com/uEbVmU for the compilation errors:

```
Compilation error    time: 0 memory: 3296 signal:0
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int Adder::operator()(const T&, const U&) [with T = DerivedA; U = DerivedB]’:
prog.cpp:48:15:   required from here
prog.cpp:37:22: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const DerivedA’ and ‘const DerivedB’)
             return a + b;
                      ^
prog.cpp:37:22: note: candidate is:
prog.cpp:12:13: note: int DerivedA::operator+(const DerivedA&) const
         int operator+(DerivedA const& a) const
             ^
```

Comment: Do you mean `Adder()(a, b);`?

Comment: I dont see the definition of `+` in the posted code. If you ask such question which doesn't even show the problem, then not even god would be able to help you.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://ideone.com/wLWqyP. The non-template is selected.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes I do mean Adder()(a, b), sorry about that.

Comment: So now the question is, is there something different between your real code and the one in my example?

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry it's from a complex scenario and I was trying to produce a representative simplified example. Will update.

Comment: @Nawaz Updated with complete code. Please see http://ideone.com/uEbVmU

Comment: @juanchopanza I had mistakenly reused the same template parameter twice in the original example. The updated code demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following change from:

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
    int operator()(T const& a, U const& b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

to:

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator()(T const& a, U const& b) -> decltype(a+b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

allows your code to compile.  The reason is that while selecting which overload to use, the signature of the instantiated function template causes a compilation error (no match for adding `a+b`, therefore `decltype(a+b)` is an error) and the function is removed from the set of possible overloads.  This leaves the non template version available and everybody wins.

Comment: That is absolute genius, and not even any illegible type_traits. Many thanks.